# Convert Postman Collection to robotframwork

Tags: postman, robotframework

How can I convert a Postman Collection into a Robot Framework test suite for automated testing of API?

The question is designed to inquire about your experiences or attempts in converting a Postman Collection to a Robot Framework test suite

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

1. Test the API call in PostMan and make sure it works
2. Click the 'Code' button to generate code
3. Select 'Python - Requests'
4. Create new python file with the copied content and install needed python libraries ; make sure to put everything inside a keyword
5. Call the new keyword from your robot test

Notes:

1. This example does not include asserts of response code and response content, which are necessary for a good test case.
2. You need to have the required libraries installed
3. Used PostMan version: v10.19

#### Step 1 and 2:

[image]

#### Step3:

[image]

#### Step4:

Python file should look like this:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword
import requests
import json
@keyword('Test API Request')
def test_api_request():
    url = "https://my_host/user/login/submission"

    payload = json.dumps({
    "data": {
        "email": "email@email",
        "password": "password",
        "submit": True
    },
    "state": "submitted"
    })
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    ## Add asserts in PostMan so that they are generated automically here
    print(response.text)
```

#### Step5:

Finally Robot test should look like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     path_to_your_python_file/python_file_name.py

*** Test Cases ***
TC_API_REQUEST_FROM_POSTMAN
    [Setup]
    Test API Request
    [Teardown]
```